# how can I check if listview1 item in not present anymore in listview2 and fire an event?

Tags: c#, listview, for-loop, foreach

I dont think I saw something like this, i searched through net but all i could find is using foreach loop.

[here I have the Listviews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llNnj.png)

What I wanted to do was If listview1 dont have any items named "Joshua", it will change listview2's "Joshua" from "Incomplete" to "Complete".

listview1 can have 2 or more "Joshua", so until all the "Joshua" are gone the listview2 must stay "Incomplete". when all the "Joshua" are gone in Listview1, thats when listview2's "joshua" be "Complete".

[this must be the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9qai.png)

I used for loop, but it doesnt change incomplete to complete. i think i might be wrong at the looping itself.

I had put this in the timer1_tick since listview1 Items can be removed when time expires.

here is my code:

```
for (int lst = 0; lst < listView2.Items.Count; lst++)
{
    for (int dgv = 0; dgv < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; dgv++)
    {
        if (listView2.Items[lst].SubItems[0].Text == listView1.Items[dgv].SubItems[0].Text )
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (listView2.Items[lst].SubItems[0].Text != listView1.Items[dgv].SubItems[0].Text ) 
        {
            listView2.Items[lst].SubItems[1].Text = "Complete";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: for (int lst = 0; lst < listView2.Items.Count; lst++)
                {
                    
                    for (int dgv = 0; dgv < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; dgv++)
                    {
                        if (listView2.Items[lst].SubItems[0].Text == listView1.Items[dgv].SubItems[0].Text )
                        {
                            continue;
   }
   else if (listView2.Items[lst].SubItems[0].Text != listView1.Items[dgv].SubItems[0].Text ) 
   {
       listView2.Items[lst].SubItems[1].Text = "Complete";
   }

                    }
                }

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop through your list view items. Your requirement is to continually check if ListView1 has a particular item (`Joshua` in this case.), and if it doesn't have that, change status in ListView2.

What I would do is create a method and pass a list of strings to it. The list of strings is a list which all items you want to search such as `Joshua`.

Then, for each item in the list, if `ListView1` contains it, then change the status of the said item in `ListView2`. Elsewhere, you'd update the list of strings with items you want to check for.

```
private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // items is a list of string which contains strings to search for, such as "Joshua"
    ChangeStatus(items);
}

private void ChangeStatus(List<string> items)
{
    foreach(string it in items)
    {
        if(!lv1.Items.Contains(it))
        {
            // Change the status of 'it' in ListView2 from Incomplete to Complete
            // Change only if status is 'Incomplete'. No point in changing if it's already 'Complete'.
        }
    }
}
```

You didn't specify if this is WPF or WinForms. If it's the former, the best way to go about this is to have two `ObservableCollection` collections for items representing each list view. And then data bind the two collections to your list views, and manipulate your `ObservableCollections` to see if items exists etc, and WPF will automatically take care of your ListView representation of that data.

Comment: that didnt worked for me but instead i came up with my own answer

Answer (score 0):

I somewhat feel retarded for using datagrids that are hidden behind the listview to make this work. but all in all it made a huge step in making it functional.

```
public void cceceec()
        {
            if (listView1.Items.Count > 0)
            {

                for (int e = 0; e < listView2.Items.Count; e++)
                {
                    for (int w = 0; w < listView1.Items.Count; w++)
                    {
                        if (listView2.Items[e].SubItems[0].Text == listView1.Items[w].SubItems[2].Text)
                        {
                            if (listView1.Items[w].SubItems[7].Text == "Finished")
                            {
                                fcounter[e] = fcounter[e] + 1;
                                for (int dd = 0; dd < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; dd++)
                                {
                                    if (listView2.Items[e].SubItems[0].Text == dataGridView1.Rows[dd].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
                                    {
                                        MessageBox.Show(fcounter[0].ToString());
                                        if (fcounter[e] == Int32.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[dd].Cells[2].Value.ToString()))
                                        {
                                            listView2.Items[e].SubItems[1].Text = "Complete";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            servings();
            label3.Text = string.Format("{0:h:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.Now);

            if(dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int lst = 0; lst < listView2.Items.Count; lst++)
                {

                    for (int dgv = 0; dgv < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; dgv++)
                    {
                        if (listView2.Items[lst].SubItems[0].Text == dataGridView1.Rows[dgv].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
                        {
                            //serv checking
                            if (dataGridView1.Rows[dgv].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "blanked")
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                            else if (dataGridView1.Rows[dgv].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "noblanked")
                            {
                                cceceec();
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }`
```